# How to optimize a python script which runs in apache and writes to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, optimization, connection-pooling, mod-wsgi

I have been testing a script in both php and its rewrite in python to leverage on python ability to create and handle connection pool. Using jmeter php script could handle around 800 request / minute and drops to 600 then 400 .

The following rewrite handles up to 1900 requests / minute but also drops to 1000 then 600 . It done on an ubuntu 12.04.4 t1.micro on aws using around 400 MB of the 600MB available for both mysql and either php or python which was a little stable. So RAM apparently is not the issue here.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 from webob import Request, html_escape
 import MySQLdb
 from DBUtils.PooledDB import PooledDB

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])

    req = Request(environ)
    username = ""
    password = ""
    fr = ""
    to = ""
    text = ""
    dlr_mask = ""
    dlr_url = ""
    mtbId = ""    

    if('username' in req.GET):
        username = html_escape(req.GET['username'])

    if('password' in req.GET):
        password = html_escape(req.GET['password'])

    if('from' in req.GET):
        fr = html_escape(req.GET['from'])

    if('to' in req.GET):
        to = html_escape(req.GET['to'])

    if('text' in req.GET):
        text = html_escape(req.GET['text'])

    if('dlr-mask' in req.GET):
        dlr_mask = html_escape(req.GET['dlr-mask'])

    if('dlr-url' in req.GET):
        dlr_url = html_escape(req.GET['dlr-url'])
        fake = Request.blank(dlr_url)
        if('mtbId' in fake.GET):
            mtbId = html_escape(fake.GET['mtbId'])


     DB_NAME = "kannel"
     DB_QUERY = """INSERT INTO send_sms(momt,sender,receiver,msgdata,dlr_mask,dlr_url,sms_type, service,boxc_id,time) VALUES('MT','{sender}','{num}','{msg}',{mask},'{url}',2,'{mId}','nalobox',UNIX_TIMESTAMP())""".format(sender = fr, num=to, msg=text ,mask = dlr_mask, url=dlr_url , mId=mtbId)
     DB_HOST = "localhost"
     DB_USER = "root"
     DB_PASS = "letmein" 





     if (fr and to and text):
         pool = PooledDB( creator = MySQLdb, mincached = 5, db = DB_NAME, host = DB_HOST, user = DB_USER, passwd= DB_PASS, charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True, maxconnections=90)
        __db = pool.connection()
        __cur = __db.cursor()
        __cur.execute(DB_QUERY)
        __cur.close()
        __db.commit()
        __db.close()
        return str("Good")
     else:  
        return str("Failure")
```

I have use apache 2 and mod_wsgi so python script is directly hit. I am wondering if this is the best approach. My constant questions are :

**question 1** Was the pool created for each request either simultaneous requests or sequential requests?
**question 2** how are the connections of the pool created? all max connections created from first and kept open for subsequent requets?
**question 3** With the code above. Is it the case that each request reinitialize the pool?
**question 4** How to make this script optimal?

thanks in advance for your explanation

**EDIT**

I use apache2 with default settings ie apache2 installed with `apt-get install apache2`. wsgi is also installed with similar commandds: `apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`. Virtualhost config is as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 <!-...-->

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/work/python

<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all  
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /sendsms /var/www/vhosts/work/python/sendsms.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Apparently MPM is prefork..

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 19 2014 21:11:10
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
   threaded:     no
   forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
-D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
-D APR_HAS_MMAP
-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
-D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Comment: The performance characteristics of the Python script under mod_wsgi will be directly influenced by the Apache MPM used and the mod_wsgi configuration. If you are doing this on the same Apache you are running your PHP application, then you are likely putting your Python script at a severe disadvantage as the default PHP setup for Apache creates problems for Python scripts. Provide more details about the Apache MPM you are using and how you configured mod_wsgi.

Comment: Saying you using default packages for Apache doesn't say anything as what that is can different between Linux distributions. You need to actually work out what MPM you are using. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Apache_Build_Information What you have shown though indicates you are using embedded mode of mod_wsgi. This will potentially be exacerbated if you are using prefork MPM.

Comment: I @Graham, I finally got your point. MPM is preforked. What can be done in this case?

Comment: For a start, use daemon mode of mod_wsgi. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Checking it up. Any remarks on the connection pool bit?

Comment: Ensure you are using one process first. In a multi process configuration it would have been one pool per process and so if requests shared across many processes, pool not helping much.